# ipfs.files.add(Buffer) function causing TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ipfs

I am trying to upload an image to ipfs using ipfs.files.add() function
but it is causing me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at App.onSubmit (App.js:70)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:265)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:571)
at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:596)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:695)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:704)
at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:676)
at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:844)
at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:852)
at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5025)
at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:19916)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2246)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5105)
at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:19978)
at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2267)
at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5081)
```

The code:

```
captureFile(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 const file=event.target.files[0];
 const reader=new window.FileReader();
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 reader.onloadend = () => {
 this.setState({buffer:Buffer(reader.result)});
 console.log('buffer',this.state.buffer);
 }

}
onSubmit(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 ipfs.files.add(this.state.buffer, ( error , result ) => {

 if(error){
   console.error(error);

 }
 else{
   console.log("success");
 }
this.setState({ipfshash : result[0].hash});
console.log('ipfshash',this.state.ipfshash);
 }

 );
 }
```

Comment: You should provide the full code, ideally a repos link. But it seems a JS issue more than an Ethereum or IPFS one. At least an issue with the lib you use which should be asked on the lib's support like gitter or github issues.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether you got the solution or not but I will tell you one solution

Please change **`ipfs.files.add`** to **`ipfs.default.files.add`**

Try! Hope it helps you.